# Authlogic HTTP Basic UserSession.find returns nil, means declarative_authorization can't get a current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, declarative-authorization, basic-authentication

When using Authlogic's HTTP Basic auth, UserSession.find returns nil since the session appears not to be set. As a result, declarative_authorization, which references the usual current_user method (as below), can't find a current user.

```
def current_user_session
    return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
    @current_user_session = UserSession.find
end

def current_user
    return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
    @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.record
end
```

Is it possible to create a session when a user auths via HTTP basic (even though that session will only last until the request closes) or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Having moved over to devise, I'm having exactly the same issue. Using HTTP basic auth, current_user is nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having fiddled with Devise, everything now seems to be working, as long as when using ActiveResource I do site = "http://user:password@domain", rather than:

```
site = "http://domain"
username = "user"
password = "password"
```

Which doesn't work. I havn't taken the time to dig into why.

Answer (score 0):

Bumping this. I'm exactly having the same issue (with the same gems - authlogic + declarative_auth).

Found the solution for me, all i needed was to copy the following code to the end of the authorization_rules.rb

```
privileges do
  privilege :manage, :includes => [:create, :read, :update, :delete]
  privilege :read, :includes => [:index, :show]
  privilege :create, :includes => :new
  privilege :update, :includes => :edit
  privilege :delete, :includes => :destroy
end
```

Comment: I don't think this is the same issue. Mine was really nothing to do with authorization, but was authlogic not returning a current_user object.